# Python Beginner: Struggling to Implement Loop Based on Conditions

Tags: python, loops, oop

I have been trying at this all day, I am going to try to explain what I am trying to do using text and code snippets.

I am working on the nursery rhyme game 'Bubblegum bubblegum in a dish' from childhood. I thought it would be a good/easy project to learn OOP in Python.

Anyway, how the game works in real life is this:

- The players are in a circle with their both of fists out
- The player that is doing the counting, goes around in the circle tapping the fists. They do one 'tap' for each word of 'Bubblegum bubblegum in a dish how many pieces do you wish?'
- An example of this is let's say I have 4 players (8 fists) the fists would be 'tapped on' as follows: Bubblegum (tap fist 1, player 1), bubblegum (tap fist 2, player 1), in (tap fist 1, player 2), a (tap fist 2, player 2), dish (tap fist 1, player 3), how (tap fist 2, player 3), many (tap fist 1, player 4), pieces (tap fist 2, player 4), do (tap fist 1, player 1), you (tap fist 2, player 1), wish (tap fist 1, player 2).

I am trying to create a looping structure for the third bullet point above, and I can't figure it out.

How my game works, is that I have player objects, and each player has a left fist and a right fist.

My player objects are as follows, they are stored in a list called game_players:

`[Player(Player 0, [Fist(Left), Fist(Right)]), Player(Player 1, [Fist(Left), Fist(Right)])]`

In my mind, I need to loop through the game_players list, access the object, then the fists to 'count' them. I come from Java Programming, so in my mind - an inner and outer loop is needed to access the fists for each object. The issue is, we also have to keep counting fists until we reach 11 (there are 11 words in the 'Bubblegum, bubble gum' rhyme).

I've tried many implementations - but I'm getting stuck between the inter/outer loop idea, and needing to count to 11 (which depending on the amount of players, will require the fists to be counted through more than one time).

I will put an code example showing one of my most recent attempts. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been working on this all day.

```
# At each index, the total number of fists is added, so the index
# of fists in play, accurately represents the user the fist object corresponds to

 fists_in_play = []

 for game_player in game_players:
  
 fists_in_play.append(game_player.fists)

 print(fists_in_play)
```

The above code ends up creating this stored in fists_in_play

`[[Fist(Left), Fist(Right)], [Fist(Left), Fist(Right)]]`

This basically stores the fists that each player currently has. The index of each set of [Fist(Left), Fist(Right)] corresponds to the number of the player (provided you recognize you have to start counting from 0). This doesn't accomplish what I want because I don't know how to integrate counting each fist 11 times. I think I am making this entirely too complicated and am unsure of what to do next.

Comment: Just blue-skying here, but you might consider having `Fist` objects instead, where each `Fist` object has a link back to its owning `Player`.  Now, you can do a single loop through the `Fist`s without worrying about the two-ness.

Comment: Another thing to consider is if you do actually need to iterate through `Fist`s at all. You could get the current `Fist` with `word_idx % 2` for whether its left or right and the player number with `word_idx // 2 % num_players`. Both zero-indexed of course.

Comment: "I will put an code example showing one of my most recent attempts." - Okay, so: **What did you want to happen** when you tried this code? (i.e., what should be in the `fists_in_play` afterward?) **What did happen**, and **how is that different**? Then: what do you expect to do after this? What do imagine is the next step, and what do you find difficult about it? (Alternatively: Why is the `fists_in_play` list supposed to be helpful for solving the problem? Is it not helpful? If not, why not?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - see edit to original post. Thanks.

Comment: @TimRoberts - Honestly - I was thinking the same thing because I recongize I am making this way too complex. Could you give me some pointers on how I would go about implementing this? Python is so 'easy' compared to other languages, I think I'm overthinking things - a lot –

Comment: What if the list were flattened, like `[Fist(Left), Fist(Right), Fist(Left), Fist(Right)]`. Would that make it possible to count through in the way that you want? Can you see how to get a result like that by modifying the loop code?